# ASP MVC3: Disable unobtrusive validation on the onsubmit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a performance problem due to a big form I have where there is a table that can contain 100+ records. The reason is that when I submit the form the validation for every single item is fired and this is causing a 5s delay which is unacceptable.

Is there a way to disable this just for this event in this form? I'm performing the validations on the onblur event and on the serverside, so I think it will be safe if I just skip it on the onsubmit event.

I've tried the following and it has not worked:

```
//1
$.validator.setDefaults({
    onsubmit: false
});

//2
var validationSettings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
validationSettings.onsubmit = false;

//3
$("form").validate().cancelSubmit = true; //This is on the onclick of the submit button
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the class `cancel` to your submit button, that will signal jquery.validate.js that validation should not be done when the submit button is clicked.

**UPDATE**

jquery.validate.js contains the following:

```
// allow suppresing validation by adding a cancel class to the submit button
inputsAndButtons.filter(".cancel").click(function () {
    validator.cancelSubmit = true;
});
```

Based on the behavior you are reporting, you must have something else attached to your submit event which is overriding the behavior of jquery.validate for a submit button with the cancel class.

Please examine each step in the image you posted of the event progress.  There is almost certainly something in that tree which will indicate where the default behavior is being overridden.

Comment: I've also tried that, but with no luck at all. I've run the "this.find("input, button").filter(".cancel")" code on my page and it actually finds the button, but I still get this on the profiler of IE:

http://imgur.com/h7Aqf

Comment: The html of the button is:

<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" title="Save" value="Save" class="Text cancel"/>

one thing that may be affecting this is that this form is inside a modal popup of IE which in some circunstances it has shown some strange behaviours I don't know if this may be one of those ocasions.

Comment: Is the modal popup populated when the page is first loaded, or does it get popluated later via AJAX?  If it is populated via AJAX, that is likely to be an issue.